# MVC pattern with multiple classes

Tags: java, model-view-controller, design-patterns

When I want to use the MVC pattern to a project which contains multiple classes what should I do ?

I should create a separate view, model, and controller for each of the relevant classes or use unique controller, view and model ?

Answer (score 0):

This is is a very high level description because each of these main "components" could be made of multiple classes. So it is fully up to you to decide of the best mapping.

Other principles, such as the separation of concerns, would suggest to have different views for different model objects. So a UserAccount, and a UserAccountView is in general a sound approach. But you could still have combo views that refer to serveral different model objects at once.

You will find many more flavors of MVC regarding the controller. The single controller monopolizing the user input and controlling all the views and commanding the domains, is no longer a reality, since many windowing system attach the controller to a window. So you'd probably have a swarm of controller, with an AppController and an additional controller for each view, e.g. UserAccountViewController, rather than a controller per domain object.

Of course, in a very simple application, with a few relatively independent domain object, each having a single view, you could find the objects as you describe them.

Comment: I am sure it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the project's complexity and the purpose for which the classes are being used. If the classes are relatively simple and will be used to achieve a single task, then it may be more economical to use a single controller, view, and model. However, if the classes are being used for larger tasks and more complex interactions, creating a separate controller, view, and model for each relevant class may be beneficial. Ultimately, it is up to you to decide how best to organize the different classes to achieve the desired goal.